# Plotting binary variable in R

Tags: r, binary, bar-chart

I have a dataframe where I created a variable (`data$adtype`) for if the tone of an ad is positive or negative. So, if it is positive, the ad gets a zero, negative then the ad gets a 1. So, I'm doing bar plots of the adtype but I'm subsetting the data by state. So, (`data$adtype[data$state=="NY"]`) for instance. For states that have both positive and negative ads, it will plot the graph correctly. The issue is, for states that only aired positive ads, it will graph a single bar and it won't even include the other variable on the graph.

When I do the `table(data$adtype[data$sate=="NY"])`, for instance
it might say:

```
0       1 
2500    3000
```

which means there are 2500 positive ads and 3000 negative ads, and it will graph both bars.

Now, if New Jersey only has positive ads,and no negative ads

```
table(data$adtype[data$sate=="NJ"])
```

I would expect this code to return the following

```
0     1
500   0
```

where there are 500 positive ads and 0 negative ads.

instead, it returns this

```
0
500
```

and it won't even place the other value on the table, nor will it graph it.

I'm trying to produce a graph where it has both binary values, 0 and 1, on the x-axis, and even if one of the values has zero ads in it, it will still include it in the graph.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Please post your data through dput

Answer (score 1):

Make your variable a `factor`:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rbinom(100, 1, .50)
x <- as.factor(x)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(table(x))
barplot(table(x[x==1]))
```

By default, `table` does not drop unused factor levels:

[image]